# Regular expression - starting and not ending with a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

How do I put a regular expression to check if a string starts with certain pattern and is NOT ending with certain pattern.

Example:

```
Must StartsWith: "US.INR.USD.CONV"
Should not end with: ".VALUE"

Passes Regex: "US.INR.USD.CONV.ABC.DEF.FACTOR"
Fails Regex Check: "US.INR.USD.CONV.ABC.DEF.VALUE"
```

I am using C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this regex based on **negative lookahead**:

```
^US\.INR\.USD\.CONV(?!.*?\.VALUE$).*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQ6eC5/1)

#### Explanation:

- `^US\.INR\.USD\.CONV` - Match `US.INR.USD.CONV` at start of input
- `(?!.*?\.VALUE$)` - Negative lookahead to make sure line is not ending with `.value`

Comment: Thanks. Dindt know I can do something like this with regex. What if I want to add OR condition like should not end with VALUE or PERCENT. Is it possible ?

Comment: @buffer_overflow yes just add `(?!.*?\.(?:VALUE|PERCENT)$)`

Comment: I think you should escape the dot before value, so it just looks for a literal `.VALUE`, "VALUE" preceded by any character, no?

Answer (score 4):

```
^US\.INR\.USD\.CONV.*(?<!\.VALUE)$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/26

Just use a negative lookbehind to make `.VALUE` is not before `$` or end of string.

```
(?<!\.VALUE)$ ==>Makes sure regex engine looks behind and checks if `.VALUE` is not there when it reaches the end of string.
```

Comment: note for people coming across this thread: JavaScript apparently doesn't support lookbehind syntax, so this won't work in JS. (but will in .NET)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regular expressions for that.  You can just use [`String.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`String.EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if(val.StartsWith("US.INR.USD.CONV") && !val.EndsWith(".VALUE"))
{
    // valid 
}
```

And as you mention in your comment to anubhava's answer you can do this to check for ".PERCENT" at the end as well.

```
if(val.StartsWith("US.INR.USD.CONV") && 
  !val.EndsWith(".VALUE") &&
  !val.EndsWith(".PERCENT"))
{
    // valid 
}
```

IMHO this makes the code much more readable and will almost definitely perform faster as well.

Comment: This does look easy and natural.